# Action result that saves a user input to an existing file ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code. I need to take the `categoryInput` and save it to a line in an already existing txt file `Category.txt` and there is something wrong with the way I am trying to save it. I'm really new to MVC and although it may seem simple I am also really quite confused as to how to implement my model and the purpose as to why it even exists...I understand what a model is but in my current context and issue I am struggling to understand.

Model code:

```
 public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int categoryID { get; set; }
        public string categoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Category(string categoryInput)
{
    var userData = categoryInput + "," + 0 + Environment.NewLine;

     var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");
     File.WriteAllText(@dataFile, userData);
     return View();
}
```

View Code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Category", "Category", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="categoryInput">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoryInput">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("List","List")'">Back</button>
        </form>
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? It just doesn't save? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: The error seems to be in the line `File.WriteAllText(@dataFile, userData);` it says that Controller.File(byte[],string) is a method that is not valid in the given context.

Comment: you have to use `System.IO.File`

Comment: Also, you need to consider using `AppendText` method in case you are trying to retain a list of data for each request in that file. more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Controllers have a File property, which conflicts with System.IO.File when you have `using System.IO` at the top. So to tell it to use System.IO.File, you must fully qualify it, ex: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText`. But keep in mind, WriteAllText probably isn't what you want either if you intend to preserve the existing contents of the file and just keep adding to it. Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8) and pick a suitable method.